# Linux file transfers slow compared to windows

Tags: files, transfer

So I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P53 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04 installed and have noticed Linux is a large percentage slower transferring files than Windows. When transferring from my Windows file server, Windows 10 will transfer at 107MB/s but Linux is around 75MB/s. I have verified the speeds by viewing the live transfer rates on the server and in my router.

Also, I have a USB 3.2 10Gb/s external enclosure NVME WD Black SN720 and when plugged into my Thunderbolt 3 port in Windows, the TB3 transfers at 1.1GB/s but Linux is 350MB/s.

When transferring files between my internal drives, in Windows I reach 1.7GB/s but in Linux I get maybe 1.1GB/s.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? My boot drive is a WD SN720 500GB, my internal data drive is a WD SN720 1TB and the external is a WD SN720 500GB. My internal drives are on PCIe 4x Gen3 ports.

For the tests, I've been using a 50GB virtual drive image. My router is a Mikrotik CCR1009 so that is how I'm able to verify speeds across network with the router.

*** Edit ***

So I just ran a benchmark in Linux and the external on TB3 held stead at 1GB/s read & write and the internal was 3.4GB/s read & 2.7GB/s write...

Comment: Just wondering -- for the transfer rates, you're not looking at just the rate as reported by the router, etc.  When transferring with Windows, the time to transfer the entire file is noticeably less?  I don't know much about Windows, but it's hard to do a perfect comparison.  For example, how are the drives formatted?  For Windows, presumably you used NTFS.  For Ubuntu, I guess you used ext4.  Does this difference matter?  If you used Ubuntu to transfer to an NTFS file system, does that put it at a disadvantage?  I don't know any of this, but maybe someone can help you ensure a fair test...

Comment: What is the the protocol you transfer files with? Is it samba? And also what is the filesystem you use on your disk. If it is NTFS, then the answer is obvious. Use linux protocols and filesystem, then you should have better rates.

Comment: @Ray I have tried formatting the internal and external drive both ways for Linux. No change. And no, I wasn't looking at just the time. The difference in time it was taking to complete tasks is actually what drew my attention to the speed difference. I do a lot of work with virtual machines and constantly copy them back and forth as well as backing up.

Comment: @Pilot6 As for how the files are transferred over the network, the Windows server is using SMBv3. I have other systems running on Linux that DO NOT have slower transfer rates when doing the same tasks. It's limited to this system.

Comment: Does that last edit mean that using TB3 there are no issues, only over SMB?

Comment: No, the benchmark reached those speeds but doing an actual file copy does not. I also have the issue with SMB transfers. My 7 year older laptop running Ubuntu doesn't have the SMB transfer issue and I manage to max out of the SATA SSD. The issue seems limited to copying actual files and only on this system.